# How to get all or specific properties of a user from a database?

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, getproperties

I'm new to grails and I would like to know how to get all the properties of a login user in an application. I've used MYSQL db to store its information such as username, passowrd, address, etc. I would like to know how to get the specific value of its properties from the database and display it on a textfield/gsp. Please help. tnx..

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing it this way... Please look into the security plugins for Grails, such as the core security plugin...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to fetch list of user object with pagination, you can use:

```
def users = User.list(params)
```

where params is map (hash) of request (CGI) parameters.
params should contains offset and max.

If you'd like to fetch user by id:

```
def users = User.get(<ID>)
```

or

```
def user = User.findById(<ID>)
```

Or by some other property:

```
def user = User.findBy<PROPERTY_NAME>(<PROPERTY_VALUE>)
```

Each of these method should return user object with all fields.
In gsp, we can display it as:

```
${user?.username}
```

or

```
${fieldValue(bean: user, field: "username")}
```